# Como eu faço para acessar os elementos DOM no Electron?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, electron

Sou novo no Electron, e estou tentando fazer uma função a partir de um click em um menu. Segue abaixo meu exemplo.

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Electron</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" value="">
    <button type="button" name="funcao" onclick="funcao()">Função</button> <br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url">
  </body>
</html>
```

Neste exemplo, ao digitar alguma coisa no input `"url"` e clicar no button, aparecerá o que foi digitado no input `"campo"`.
O que queria é fazer o mesmo mas clicando no menu `"Função"`.

`main.js` (somente na parte desejada, que seria a parte do menu com a função logo embaixo)

```
  {
    label: 'Função',
    click () { funcao(); }
  },

function funcao() {
  document.getElementById("campo").value = document.getElementById("url").value;
}
```

O erro é:

> "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

Answer (score -1):

dá uma olhada no código abaixo:

```
<html lang="pt-br" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Electron</title>    
  </head>
  <body>  
    <input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" value="">
    <button type="button" id="demo" onclick="funcao()">Função</button><br/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url">

    <script>
        function funcao() {    
            document.getElementById("campo").value = document.getElementById("url").value;
        }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

execute aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/eltonpering/3prg6pj0/

Comment: Deste modo está fazendo algo que já estava fazendo no meu, mas ontem mesmo consegui achar alguma coisa na documentação do Electron. No `main.js`, na iniciação da janela, coloquei o seguinte: `mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript('document.getElementById("campo").value = "teste"')`. Mas mesmo assim, obrigado.